# Expressionengine conditionals

Tags: if-statement, expressionengine, conditional-statements

am having trouble with a conditional in EE

In an events channel, there's a field for excerpt, after_event_excerpt as well as start_date and end_date

I basically want to show the after_event_excerpt if

1. There is an after_event_excerpt (field not compulsory)

   AND
2. Either the start_date > current_time OR start_date AND end_date > current_time (as end_date is not a compulsory field)

I came up with this, but the page won't load due to errors..

{if event_after_excerpt AND event_start_date > current_time || event_start_date > current_time AND event_end_date > current_time}}

```
            <p class="event_description">{event_after_excerpt}</p>

            {if:else}

            <p class="event_description">{event_excerpt}</p>

            {/if}
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to show the `{event_after_excerpt}` if the event is in the past, not the future? I'm going to operate on that assumption.

```
{if event_after_excerpt AND event_start_date < current_time AND event_end_date < current_time}
    <p class="event_description">{event_after_excerpt}</p>
{if:else}
    <p class="event_description">{event_excerpt}</p>
{/if}
```

So, if you have something in `{event_after_excerpt}`, and the event starts in the past, and it ends in the past (an empty end date will be equivalent to 0, so it's always in the past), then show `{event_after_excerpt}`.

Comment: Derek that works fantastically, thank you very much. In my head I had to test that event_after_date existed before including it in the if statement but I guess EE just ignores it. Thanks once again as now the editors if they're feeling lazy can add some after event text before the event knowing that when it's passed it will appear as if by magic!